# view timestamp in HighChart

Tags: postgresql, highcharts

I am reading data from a postgresql database

```
select id as x , y from myTable
```

and sending it to to the client and displaying it into highchart.
if i send data in

```
{
    "x" : 123,
    "y" : 0.12
}
```

it is displayed correctly.
but when i send date in `x` it does not view any data on the chart.

```
select time_created::timestamp::date as x , y from myTable

{
    "x" : "2017-05-09",
    "y" : 0.12
}
```

someone told me that i have to convert date into number and then while viewing i have to parse it back to a date.

my question is how can i get a time stamp from the database just like an integer value so that i can send it to the Client and then how to parse it to view in high chart.

Comment: `select extract(epoch from time_created::timestamp::date) as x , y from myTable`

Comment: use `Date.parse()` to convert date to millisecond format which is used in highcharts

Comment: You can pull the date however you want, but when you send it to the chart as data, it needs to be in epoch time, as milliseconds. The chart will handle all of the conversion back to human readable dates anywhere within the chart, you don't need to convert it back unless you intend to use it outside of the chart as well.

Comment: You can use Date.parse() method.

```Date.parse('2017-05-09')```